# What would be the tight asymptotic runtime (Big Theta) for these algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

**Question 1**

```
 public void guessWhat1(int N){
  for (int i=N; i>0, i=i/2){
  for (int j=0; j<i*2; j+=1){
  System.out.println(“Hello World”);
  }
 }
}
```

The first loop will run for log(n). 
The second loop will run for log(n).

The upper bound is O(log^2(n). What would be Big Θ?

**Question 2**

```
 public void guessWhat2(int N) {
 int i=1, s=1;
 while (s<=N) {
  i += 1;
  s = s + i;
 }
}
```

The upper bound for this is O(n). I am not quite sure about the Big Θ.

It would great if someone could clarify on these. Thank You

Comment: Advice for **1)**: *(i)* be cautious about the meaning of "`n`" for different loops, *(ii)* are you sure that the second (inner) loop is `log n`?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog thanks for your advice. Initially I thought its (n), but since its multiplying *2, wouldn't it be log(n)? I saw similar case in other examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets get clear with the definitions of the notations first.

**Big O**: It denotes the **upper bound** of the algorithm.

**Big Theta**: It denotes the **average bound** of the algorithm.

For your first question

```
public void guessWhat1(int N){
  for (int i=N; i>0, i=i/2){
  for (int j=0; j<i*2; j+=1){
  System.out.println(“Hello World”);
  }
 }
}
```

For i=N, inner loop runs 2N times, i=N/2 inner loop runs for N times, for i=N/4 inner loop runs for N/2 times..... 
so the total complexity = O(2N+N+N/2+N/4+...+1) 
which is equal to O(N(2+1+1/2+1/4+....1/N))= O(N(3+1/2+1/4+....1/N))

N(3+1/2+1/4+....1/N)
= N( 3 + 1 - (0.5)^logN ) = O(N(4-1/N)) = O(N)
So the complexity is O(N), even in theta notation its the same N as the above loops takes the same time for all cases.

For your second question

```
public void guessWhat2(int N) {
 int i=1, s=1;
 while (s<=N) {
  i += 1;
  s = s + i;
 }
}
```

The while loop takes O(sqrt(N)). Same as above, here also the theta notation will also be the same as big O notation, which is sqrt(N).

The theta notation varies from big O if input has multiple cases. Lets take an example of insertion sort https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort where N is the size of the input array. If the input array is already sorted it takes linear time, but if the input array is reverse sorted it takes N^2 time to sort the array.

So in that case for insertion sort, the time complexity is O(N^2).

For best case it is theta(N) and for worst case its theta(N^2).

Comment: @Chandini Thanks for your explanation. You said that the O(sqrt(n)) is same as above log(n). Does this means that log(n) = sqrt(n) because their graphs are different. Could you please clarify on this? Thanks

Comment: No, I meant for the second question, the theta notation will also be same as big O which is sqrt(N). Modifying the answer to avoid confusion.

Comment: I'm with @meowgoesthedog - that first one smells a lot like O(n).

Comment: @moreON and meowgoesthedog thank you. Modified my answer

Comment: @moreON Thank you

Comment: @Chandini Thanks a lot for clarifying it. Will really appreciate if you could recommend any source when can I get a better understanding about complexity analysis to avoid such confusions in the future?

Comment: For starters you could look into https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fundamentals-of-algorithms/#AnalysisofAlgorithms @Prince